# Error after enable the use_flat_Catalog_category option in admin catalog,

Tags: magento-1.9, error, catalog, indexing

After enable the use_flat_Catalog_category option in admin catalog , and i did reindex, then catalog_category_flat_store_1 table was create.

And then when i try to launch the store, it's show below SQL error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.thumbnail' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`level`, `main_table`.`path`, `main_table`.`position`, `main_table`.`is_active`, `main_table`.`is_anchor`, `main_table`.`name`, `main_table`.`url_key`, `main_table`.`thumbnail`, `main_table`.`cattop_thumb` FROM `tt_catalog_category_flat_store_1` AS `main_table` WHERE (is_active = '1') AND (catslider = '1') ORDER BY name ASC
```

because catalog flat table does not have thumbnail column.

And i understand that catalog_flat_table column are created based on below sql query

```
SELECT `tt_eav_attribute`.* FROM `tt_eav_entity_type` INNER JOIN `tt_eav_attribute` ON tt_eav_attribute.entity_type_id = tt_eav_entity_type.entity_type_id WHERE  (tt_eav_entity_type.entity_type_code = 'catalog_category')
```

even this query also does not have attribute name like 'thumbnail'

Comment: Have you rebuilt the flat catalog indexes?

Comment: What does `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tt_catalog_category_flat_store_1` show you?

Comment: Thanks fschmengler,  i found and correct the problem, it because of my Installed theme mistake.

Comment: Feel free to add your solution as an answer and accept it, so that this does not count as unanswered anymore

Answer (score 0):

Attributes of the `media` type like `thumbnail` are always included in the flat index (unlike other attributes where it depends on the "Use in product listing" setting).

So since you just enabled the flat index for the first time, this probably means that it has not been built correctly. Go to `System > Index Management` in the admin panel and rebuild the index.

If that does not help, try to flush the DDL cache with the following PHP script (burn after executing):

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
    ->getConnection('core_write')
    ->resetDdlCache();
```

Comment: Thanks fschmengler, I have found the problem, "thumbnail" is not core magento property for catalog_category.

Because it was created from my installed theme.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed the fact that you were talking about the category flat index, not the product flat index.